# How to force a test run last in visual studio using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

So in my test suite, I have an abstract base class that my integration tests inherit from. Each derivation of this base class has their own set of tests.  The assertions that the child classes make are run through protected methods on the base class.  During those assertions, the base class logs which values in a dictionary have been tested.  After the child classes have run all their tests, I want the base class to run a test that verifies all the correct things were tested.

A few disclaimers:

1. Yes, I know this is an ordered test, and that those are frowned
   upon.  However, this is something I want to do anyway.
2. I know this is a test that tests my test suite, in a sense.  While this is
   often frowned upon, I find it useful. If you want your tests to
   genuinely be your documentation, it is good to have some rudimentary
   tests that verify some basic things about your documentation - that
   it's complete, for example.  (In most projects, this would probably
   be overkill and not worth it. In this particular project, however,
   it is both a personal project and an experiment in working with 100%
   code coverage.)

For now, I have marked the summary test with both `[Test]` and `[TestFixtureTearDown]`, which does make the test run at the end. However, it also means that when the test fails, the test suite gets angry because a tear down failed.  What I want in an ideal world is something like [RunLast].  Any ideas on how one might be able to accomplish this?

Example of the code currently:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class AttributesTests : IntegrationTests
{
    [Inject]
    public IAttributesMapper AttributesMapper { get; set; }

    protected abstract String tableName { get; }

    private Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<String>> table;
    private List<String> testedNames;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        testedNames = new List<String>();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        table = AttributesMapper.Map(tableName);
    }

    [Test, TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void AllNamesTested()
    {
        var missingNames = table.Keys.Except(testedNames);
        Assert.That(missingNames, Is.Empty, tableName);
    }

    [Test, TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void NoNamesTestedNultipleTimes()
    {
        var duplicateNames = testedNames.Where(n => testedNames.Count(cn => cn == n) > 1).Distinct();
        Assert.That(duplicateNames, Is.Empty, tableName);
    }

    protected void AssertAttributes(String name, IEnumerable<String> attributes)
    {
        testedNames.Add(name);

        Assert.That(table.Keys, Contains.Item(name), tableName);

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            Assert.That(table[name], Contains.Item(attribute));

            var actualAttributeCount = table[name].Count(a => a == attribute);
            var expectedAttributeCount = attributes.Count(a => a == attribute);
            Assert.That(actualAttributeCount, Is.EqualTo(expectedAttributeCount));
        }

        var extraAttributes = table[name].Except(attributes);
        Assert.That(extraAttributes, Is.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the things about NUnit is that you can choose, on a run-by-run basis, which specific tests to run, so you won't always be able to guarantee that all of them will be run.

Comment: That is true, and I do have occasions where I've partially run tests in a class, so the summary tests fail. With that in mind, any time you run all the tests in a given test class (let alone the whole test suite), those tests will be fine.  So while certainly not ideal, not a terrible problem (in my view currently, anyway)

Comment: So in essence you're adding a code coverage metric to the test suite, which should report 100% on a complete run but is (acceptably) less than that on a partial run?

Comment: Exactly.  This is admittedly not best practice - the project in which I am doing this is an experiment in testing, TDD, and 100% coverage. So I'm playing around with some things. :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
namespace ZZZ
public class ZZZZZ {
  [Test]
  public void ZZZZLastTest() {
    // Whatever . . . 
  }
}
```

Comment: Nunit will execute the test cases mostly in alphabetical order. so , having name started with z will make your test case run at the last.:) 

simple but awesome fix

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit `[LastTest]`-like attribute that I am aware off but I believe you can go with `[Suite]` instead.

I know this JUnit approach to suites will execute your test classes in lineair order as they are defined (although there is no guarantee to the order in which your tests inside one class are executed).

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ CalculatorTestAdd.class, CalculatorTestSubtract.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

Here `CalculatorTestSubtract` will be executed last. Keeping this in mind, I would say that you should create a suite which has your summary test at the end.

Looking at [NUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.4.5), I see that something should be equally possible:

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  private class AllTests
  {
    [Suite]
    public static IEnumerable Suite
    {
      get
      {
        ArrayList suite = new ArrayList();
        suite.Add(new OneTestCase());
        suite.Add(new AssemblyTests());
        suite.Add(new NoNamespaceTestFixture());
        return suite;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll have to do some tests to see if they get executed linearly because an `ArrayList` is not guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: So in my case, the summary tests should be run after all the tests in each derivation of the base class - if there are three concrete derivations of the base class, then the test should be run after each derivation is done with its tests (so three instances of the test, basically, directly tied to a concrete implementation of the base class).  My fear is that the suite approach will leave the summary tests too disconnected from the concrete implementations.

Comment: You'll have to remember to put them in the right order inside your suite and they will have to be in a different class, but that's the only solution as far as I know.